# How can I split a row in a CSV-file into multiple rows using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, data-analysis

I have a CSV-file with only a single line, but with a lot of the same column headers (NOT duplicates). My final goal is to analyze the value of a given column dependent on the value of the previous column with the same name (which is not the column adjacent to it).

My data might look like this:

```
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
| ***start block*** | stimulus | words.RT | words.ACC | ***end block***  | ***start block*** | stimulus | words.RT | words.ACC | ***end block***  |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                   | pic1.png | 2300     | 1         |                  |                   | pic2.png | 2401     | 0         |                  |
+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+
```

and so forth.

Now, I would like to be able to analyze the values of e.g. words.RT depending on the value of words.ACC in the previous block.

I'm not sure what the best approach to this is. I tried loading the CSV into a pandas-dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd 

file = "01.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=";")
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip("\t")
df.columns = df.columns.str.strip(".34")
df = df.iloc[[0]]
```

which basically gives me a datatable looking like the one I showed before. Is it possible to split the row into multiple rows according to the blocks? To me, it looks like I would need a three-dimensional array in order to encode the blocks? Is that even possible with pandas?

Comment: your columns repreats every 4 columns - so you could try to get `df.iloc[ : , 0:4]` and `df.iloc[ : , 4:8]` and append one after another.

Comment: thx, that would work for a smaller file, but I only showed the first two blocks, the file has 630 columns. any way to write this in a general statement?

Comment: use `for`-loop with `iloc[ : , i : i+4]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create

```
df1 = df.iloc[ : , 0:4]
df2 = df.iloc[ : , 4:8]
```

and append them

```
df = df1.append(df2)
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A1': [1,2],
    'B1': [3,4],
    'C1': [5,6],
    'D1': [7,8],
    
    'A2': [1,2],
    'B2': [3,4],
    'C2': [5,6],
    'D2': [7,8],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

df1 = df.iloc[: , 0:4]
df1.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

df2 = df.iloc[: , 4:8]
df2.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

df = df1.append(df2)
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

print(df)
```

---

If you have more blocks then you can use `for`-loop and

```
df.iloc[ : , i:i+4]
```

---

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A1': [1,2],
    'B1': [3,4],
    'C1': [5,6],
    'D1': [7,8],
    
    'A2': [1,2],
    'B2': [3,4],
    'C2': [5,6],
    'D2': [7,8],

    'A3': [1,2],
    'B4': [3,4],
    'C5': [5,6],
    'D6': [7,8],
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# get first block
new_df = df.iloc[:, 0:4]
new_df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

# get other blocks
for i in range(4, len(df.columns), 4):
    temp_df = df.iloc[:, i:i+4]
    temp_df.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
    new_df = new_df.append( temp_df )

new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)
print(new_df)
```

---

**EDIT:**

The same but with variable `block_size` and numbers as column's names.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'A1': [1,2],
    'B1': [3,4],
    'C1': [5,6],
    'D1': [7,8],
    
    'A2': [1,2],
    'B2': [3,4],
    'C2': [5,6],
    'D2': [7,8],

    'A3': [1,2],
    'B3': [3,4],
    'C3': [5,6],
    'D3': [7,8],

    'A4': [1,2],
    'B4': [3,4],
    'C4': [5,6],
    'D4': [7,8],    
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

block_size = 4

# get first block
new_df = df.iloc[:, 0:block_size]

# set numbers for columns
new_df.columns = list(range(block_size))

# get other blocks
for i in range(block_size, len(df.columns), block_size):
    temp_df = df.iloc[:, i:i+block_size]

    # set the same numbers for columns
    temp_df.columns = list(range(block_size))
    
    new_df = new_df.append( temp_df )

# after loop reset rows numbers (indexes)
new_df = new_df.reset_index(drop=True)

print(new_df)
```

Comment: Somehow this just gives me a dataframe with the first and last block of the original file. I have 18 columns per block and basically only adjusted that in your code (18 instead of 4 in getting the first block and within the for-loop and naming 18 columns)

Comment: did you use correct indentations ? `append()` has to be inside loop. If you use `append()` after loop then you can get only first and last block.